# Why is it not giving memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have this code (modified from a tutorial I am following):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@class Car;
@class Person;

@interface Person: NSObject

@property Car* owningCar;

@end


@implementation Person:NSObject

-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Person is gone");
}

@end


@interface Car:NSObject

@property Person* owner;

@end

@implementation Car:NSObject

-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Car is gone");
}

@end




void testRefCycle () {
    Person* me = [[Person alloc] init];
    Car* civic = [[Car alloc] init];
    me.owningCar = civic;
    civic.owner = me;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        testRefCycle();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I opened up Profiler Leaks, and ran it, expecting to get Leaks, but nothing shows up. Why is there no leak if this creates a reference cycle?

When I ran the project, there is also no output. Why is there no output if there is no leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* a leak, which is why there is no output — your `dealloc` methods never run.

But the leak detector never has a chance to detect it, because your program comes to an end in a millionth of a second. You do not have any persistent state over the longer term, which is what is needed for something to count as a leak.

If you ran `testRefCycle` in an app, for example, where the app itself persists over time, you would see the leak reported. But you are not going to see it in a one-line command-line program without a run loop, which is what you've got.

Comment: That is very strange it only captures the leak at 6th second after I added a `getchar` in the end. I guess the Profiler does have its limitations.

Comment: The profiler works by pausing your app every few fractions of a second and taking a snapshot of used pointers. So if your program doesn't run long enough, it won't have enough data. An easy way to test short code like this is to put it in a loop and just run it a couple thousand times or so. Another advantage of that is that any small leak is repeated so often that it's easier to spot.